# Functionality of DFP - targeted ads

Tags: ads, google-dfp

I have a question about a functionality of DFP, here the situation.

I ‘ve ads displayed on my website managed by DFP.
But some partners would like that when a person come from their website on my website, they don’t see ads from competitors or else they don’t see ads at all.
So, the idea would be when a surfer click on a URL (link) or if he come from a domain ([www.website.com](http://www.website.com)), it creates a session for this user during all the time the browser stay opened.

Is it possible with DFP ? Without DFP?
And if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

DFP offers you the chance to block Advertisers using its functionality: Unified advertiser exclusions to block advertisers' ads

More info here: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6019536

A solution to your problem could be to create a new Ad Unit in your DFP with the exclusions you need applied. Then create the Line or Lines aligned to your business with this new Ad Unit.

Finally in your source code you will have to check the origin of the user and call DFP with your new adUnit or with the previous one depending on the origin (I would do it checking a cookie).

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. 
I will see if we can do that and I will be back to keep you informed about.

Comment: I've looked the link : https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6019536 but I think it's only for DFP premium.
I'm using DFP Small Business so I have not the functionnality "unified advertiser exclusions".

Do you know about any other solution ? Thanks ;)

Comment: @MarionG What comes to my mind is to do it manually via JavaScript. Combining targeting of DFP + using cookies + using the `document.referer`.

With the `document.referer` you can check the previous URL so you can check if it's one of the domains you want to blacklist or not. Depending on that, I would create a cookie with different values depending on the cases you want to control. After that, for every DFP tag, you should set a targeting to say if it the origin of the visitor is from a blacklist domain or not. Then in your DFP Dashboard you can use that target to serve the proper campaigns

Answer (score 0):

You can store referral domain value into cookie or session storage on users first visit. Then create targeting on site with key/values. Something like

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("referral",referralCookieValue)
```

In dfp set targeting with Key-values where "referral" is not "www.website.com". That way everyone will see that ads except those from "www.website.com"